# Proving a subsequential limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ be two bounded sequences. Define the sequence $(u_n) = (s_1,t_1,s_2,t_2,\ldots)$. Suppose
$a$ is a subsequential limit of $(u_n)$. Proof that $a$ is a subsequential limit of $(s_n)$ or $(t_n)$. I don't really know how to begin.

Comment: Hint. Assume that $u_{k_n}$ converges to $a$. If there are infinitely many $k$ such that $u_{n_k}=s_m$ for some $m$, we are done. If not, $u_{n_k}$ is $t_m$ for some $m$, for all but finitely many $k$.

Comment: Alternatively, use the fact that if $x$ is not a subsequential limit of $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, then $x$ has an open nbhd $U$ such that $x_n\notin U$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.